# C# UDP Socket client and server

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, activex

My first question here. I am new to this kind of programming, and i've only programmed .NET web sites and forms.

Now, the company I work at, asks me to make an ActiveX component, that listens to UDP messages, and turns them into events.

The UDP msgs are send from Avaya system, so i was told that to test my ActiveX, at first I need to create an app, that only sends UDP (only one button that sends pre-defined UDP string). And then create listener socket, ordinary C# app, that will get those transmitted UDP string from the tests app. Both apps will work on the same machine.

Later, when i get this working, i need to make the listener an ActiveX component, but first things first.

I need to know if there are any good tutorials about this, and any idea on how to start? I am sorry for my ignorance, but i am really new on this and i don't really have any time to learn this since it has to be done in 2 weeks.

Thanks in advance.

edit: I managed to create 2 simple console applications, and was sending UDP messages between them successfully. The sender will be only for testing, and now I need to re-make my receiver to get the UDP message and 'translate' it to events. And lastly, to make it an ActiveX control...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Simple server and client:

```
public struct Received
{
    public IPEndPoint Sender;
    public string Message;
}

abstract class UdpBase
{
    protected UdpClient Client;

    protected UdpBase()
    {
        Client = new UdpClient();
    }

    public async Task<Received> Receive()
    {
        var result = await Client.ReceiveAsync();
        return new Received()
        {
            Message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Buffer, 0, result.Buffer.Length),
            Sender = result.RemoteEndPoint
        };
    }
}

//Server
class UdpListener : UdpBase
{
    private IPEndPoint _listenOn;

    public UdpListener() : this(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,32123))
    {
    }

    public UdpListener(IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        _listenOn = endpoint;
        Client = new UdpClient(_listenOn);
    }

    public void Reply(string message,IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        var datagram = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        Client.Send(datagram, datagram.Length,endpoint);
    }

}

//Client
class UdpUser : UdpBase
{
    private UdpUser(){}

    public static UdpUser ConnectTo(string hostname, int port)
    {
        var connection = new UdpUser();
        connection.Client.Connect(hostname, port);
        return connection;
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        var datagram = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        Client.Send(datagram, datagram.Length);
    }

}

class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create a new server
        var server = new UdpListener();

        //start listening for messages and copy the messages back to the client
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
            while (true)
            {
                var received = await server.Receive();
                server.Reply("copy " + received.Message, received.Sender);
                if (received.Message == "quit")
                    break;
            }
        });

        //create a new client
        var client = UdpUser.ConnectTo("127.0.0.1", 32123);

        //wait for reply messages from server and send them to console 
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var received = await client.Receive();
                    Console.WriteLine(received.Message);
                    if (received.Message.Contains("quit"))
                        break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Write(ex);
                }
            }
        });

        //type ahead :-)
        string read;
        do
        {
            read = Console.ReadLine();
            client.Send(read);
        } while (read != "quit");
    }
}
```

Comment: As the OP is explicitly asking for UDP, you should not lead him in the wrong directions. UdpClient (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) would be the better solution for his problem...

Comment: Yes, they ask for UDP, not TCP. I made some test listener and server, but can't connect them. When I send the msg from the server, the client is not getting it.

I thought at first my company FW is blocking the transfer, but then again both apps (both are console apps) are running at the same time on the same machine, so... Any thoughts?

Comment: Granted! Corrected my mistake with a small demo

Comment: Thanks. It did help me to understand more of how it works, and managed to create 2 simple console applications(listener and sender), and was sending UDP messages between them successfully. The sender will be only for testing, and now I need to re-make my receiver to get the UDP message and 'translate' it to events. And lastly, to make it an ActiveX control... Any heads up where how i shoud start? Note that i already have made this before, but as input got the events, and now will get string, and did it for desktop app, now i need to take that code out and create an activex.. Stupid business :)

Comment: Send me an email and w'll see

Comment: Your email is not shown on your profile. Can you please provide it for me? Thanks.

btw, i re-created winforms apps, sender on one PC, and the listener on my laptop. When the sender sends UDP string, the lsitener gets it and fires an event that says: "you get UDP message: "my string here".

Next, activex.

Comment: Ok, managed to make an activex control. It calls a function "startthread" and it is waiting for event. The event is UDP message from an Avaya server. The function that is listening interprets that string and writes the data with some additinal info to a database as well as in log.txt. My last assignemt is - to return the data to the web application that is calling the StartThread functio (which is supposed to work in the bacground. Any way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

Simple server and client:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create UDP client
        int receiverPort = 20000;
        UdpClient receiver = new UdpClient(receiverPort);

        // Display some information
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Upd receiving on port: " + receiverPort);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------\n");

        // Start async receiving
        receiver.BeginReceive(DataReceived, receiver);

        // Send some test messages
        using (UdpClient sender1 = new UdpClient(19999))
            sender1.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi!"), 3, "localhost", receiverPort);
        using (UdpClient sender2 = new UdpClient(20001))
            sender2.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi!"), 3, "localhost", receiverPort);

        // Wait for any key to terminate application
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        UdpClient c = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
        IPEndPoint receivedIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        Byte[] receivedBytes = c.EndReceive(ar, ref receivedIpEndPoint);

        // Convert data to ASCII and print in console
        string receivedText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);
        Console.Write(receivedIpEndPoint + ": " + receivedText + Environment.NewLine);

        // Restart listening for udp data packages
        c.BeginReceive(DataReceived, ar.AsyncState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Server

```
public void serverThread()
{
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(8080);
    while(true)
    {
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
        string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
        lbConnections.Items.Add(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() 
                                + ":" +  returnData.ToString());
    }
}
```

And initialize the thread

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thdUDPServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverThread));
    thdUDPServer.Start();
}
```

Client

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
    udpClient.Connect(txtbHost.Text, 8080);
    Byte[] senddata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");
    udpClient.Send(senddata, senddata.Length);
}
```

Insert it to button command.

Source: http://technotif.com/creating-simple-udp-server-client-transfer-data-using-c-vb-net/

Comment: Thanks!
Here are the namespaces you need for this:   
"using System.Threading;"  "using System.Net;"   "using System.Net.Sockets;"  "using System.Text;"