# Alert after an event in C#

Tags: c#, events, dll

I'm still working on a project, and asked two questions before:

[C# UDP Socket client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786668/c-sharp-udp-socket-client-and-server)

[How to return data from void function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956212/how-to-return-data-from-void-function)

Now, I've made the ActiveX, and I need the client to listen to the event. I've used the example in the second link, and it worked - kinda. The Activex DLL is raising an event, the client app is listening to it, but can't do anything with it, can't even send notification on client side.

In the DLL i have this:

```
    public event EventHandler<NewMessageArgs> OnMessage;

    public class NewMessageArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public NewMessageArgs(string message)
            {
                Message = message;
            }
            public string Message;
            public string _message { get { return Message; } set { Message = value; } }
        }

private Thread UdpThread;
        public void StartThread()
        {
            #region StartThread
            try
            {
                UdpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListen));
                UdpThread.IsBackground = true;
                UdpThread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            #endregion
        }

[ComVisible(true)]
        public void StartListen()
        {
            #region StartListen
            private const int listenPort = 11000;
            try
            {
                int Port = 11000;
                UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(Port);
                IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, Port);

                byte[] receiveBytes;

                while (true)
                {
                    receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteIpEndPoint);
                    string receiveData = Encoding.Default.GetString(receiveBytes);
                    //do some other stuff, and on event when MSG arrives:

               OnMessage(this, new NewMessageArgs(receiveData));
```

And on the client that is using this DLL I have:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    public static string MSG;

    static public ActiveXComponent.Class1 activex;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            activex = new ActiveXComponent.Class1();
            activex.getConnectionString(data_connection);
            //activex.OnMessage += ProcessMessage; - I tried this first, the later second, but still same result
            activex.OnMessage += new EventHandler<NewMessageArgs>(ProcessMessage);
            activex.StartThread();
        }
    }

    public void ProcessMessage(object sender, NewMessageArgs args)
    {
        MSG= args.Message;
        this.txtIncomingVDN.Text = MSG;
        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('A message has arrived: \n" + MSG+ " .');</script>");    
    }
```

In the debug mode, I can see that the client is listening and stores the data in the MSG variable. However, the text in the textbox is NOT changing, nor can I make the response, since it gives me an error "Response is not available in this context".

Basically, the DLL rises an event when UDP message receives, the client gets that event and makes changes (textbox and in future some other stuff).

Any solution? I'm dead tired of this project and need to finish it ASAP, so that I can turn to other, more important things.

Comment: Use Deligates ... with events it will give you the solution

Comment: Are you calling an event tied to a web page? ....

Comment: No, the event triggers when UDP message arrives from an Avaya system. It's a string that in the DLL it is splitting, using the data, and so on, that's the least of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to invoke the Text change on the UI thread. In WPF you can do this with

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { txtIncomingVDN.Text = MSG; }));
```

In windows forms it's something like

```
txtIncomingVDN.beginInvoke(() => { txtIncomingVDN.Text = MSG; }));
```

Comment: It's web based application in c# and .NET 2.0 only, so this won't work. Any other idea?