# Get IP address of devices that respond to broadcast

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, broadcast

I have successfully created UDP sockets in C#. One to broadcast a command out to look for an device on the network. The other to receive the response data. I get the correct responses from the devices.

The question I have is how do I get the actual IP address of the devices that responds. I'm sending and receiving asynchronously on the receive side I am using socket.BeginReceiveFrom(...). It is VERY important that I know and save the IP address from each responding device.

Thanks, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about `((IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address`? But maybe this only works for tcp... See [`Socket.RemoteEndPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Tried ((IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.  There is no .Address selection for .RemoteEndPoint. Could be a UDP socket thing.

Comment: `Address` is a propertey of `IPEndPoint`. The `RemoteEndPoint` property of `Socket` is of type `EndPoint` and you have to cast it correctly to `IPEndPoint` (if it is one), it seems you missed some parantheses...but anyway, the docs say it's for connection-oriented protocols, so probably not for udp.

Comment: Can a broadcast socket be setup using TcP socket? Most of the examples I find use UDP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25442454/6574422

Comment: If there a way to modify the code to do UDP broadcasts?

Comment: This returns the IP address of the machine I am running the code from. I really need to know the IP address of the device that responded.

Comment: Using socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epServer1) then ((IPEndPoint)epServer1).Address.ToString());  René Vogt answer helped me resolve this issue. Thanks to all that responded...