# How to make UdpClient non blocking

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, udp, udpclient

I am new in Socket programming and C#. I am trying to create an application in which I am using `UdpClient`.

But even there is data on socket but sometime the `Receive function` not receiving any data and goes to blocking state.
Just to prevent this from blocking I use a counter.
The receive function is on thread.

And in `main function` I have create a counter

```
int count = 0;
bool ret = IsDataReceived();
while(!ret && count < 30)
{
  ret = IsDataReceived();
  count++;
}

if(count>= 30)
{
thread.abort();

udpclient.close();
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Data Received");
}
```

I am currenlty doing like this but I want to know that how can I make a `UdpClient` non blocking.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# UDP Socket client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786668/c-sharp-udp-socket-client-and-server)

Comment: **Never** use the `Thread.Abort` method. It is there only for exceptional cases. If you don't know those cases, then you definitely don't need `Thread.Abort`.

Comment: @dymanoid ok sir but I don't find other ways

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how is written your function IsDataReceive, if you are using:

```
UdpClient.Receive
```

this operation Blocks until a message returns on the socket

if you dont want to have a blocking operation you could use:

```
UdpClient.ReceiveAsync
```

Comment: IsDataRecived return the bool value if the data received that the value becomes true. Can you post sample code of ReceiveAsync

Comment: you have a beautiful sample there: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example